# Cost of eating in San Francisco

Tags: budget, planning, food-and-drink

My fiance and I are planning to fly out to San Francisco in September for our honeymoon.  This will be our first cross-continental trip together as a couple, so I want things to go well and for no moajor financial problems to crop up.

The problem is, I have no idea what the cost of eating at resturaunts is like out there, in particular in the San Francisco area.

What is the approximate cost of eating in the San Francisco area as a traveller?

Comment: "expensive" or "cheap" is such a relative thing.  Try sites such as the following http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/city_result.jsp?country=United+States&city=San+Francisco%2C+CA

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 Looks like a range of around $60-80 for two people for a mid-range meal.  I tell you, it was really hard to find a tool that would give me that data, and NOT the price of just buying groceries.

Comment: I would say it looks fine as a question but remove the parts about reducing the cost, it sounds like another question.

Comment: SF is among the most expensive cities in the USA, but you can get pretty good local and cheap food (such as seafood chowder) and in general I would find USA cheaper than western Europe.  Enjoy your trip!

Comment: On the other side, I found USA way more expensive and with less quality food-wise than Western Europe. And I've only visited Georgia and Tennessee, nothing fancy like NYC.

Comment: As one data point, the price of food at the ball park (AT&T Stadium) seems pretty reasonable by Toronto standards. Just check out yelp.com, chowhound and similar foodie sites (maybe Diners, Dives and Drive-ins) and then look at the menus from the restaurant websites for things that look interesting to you. You'll get an idea very fast, specific to your needs and interests. If you're from Europe, don't forget to add for tax and tip (if there is table service) above the menu prices (maybe +30%). So a US price of $15 for an entree would be roughly EUR 15 after tax and tip.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99: It does not make sense at all to compare with prices in "Western Europe" and putting cheap countries like Spain or Portugal in the same group as utterly expensive countries like Norway or Switzerland.

Comment: Sounds like "mid range" meals are in my high range.

Comment: My comment was definitely an opinion hence why I said "I would find..." I was spending over 10 Euros on average for full sit down meals all over Europe while I could find an equivalent for under $10 USD

Comment: I think this question is valid like some other "how expensive is...?" questions http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/how-expensive-is-belgium?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool such as [numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/city_result.jsp?country=United+States&city=San+Francisco%2C+CA) to find rough prices such as cheap meals, price of beer, price of groceries, and transportation.

You can also do price comparisons between cities e.g. compare San Francisco to your home town and you get an approximate feeling for how much things cost relative to where you are familiar with.

Another idea is to look up sites like Trip Advisor and do a restaurant search and filter based on $.